# Query Optimization for INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this query below:

```
SELECT a.id, b.item_name 
FROM table_1 as a 
INNER JOIN table_2 as b on a.item_id = b.item_id
```

There is index on `a.bid` as primary, and a index on `a.item_id` and there is an index on `b.item_id` as primary and index on `b.item_name`

However when I run the query through the `EXPLAIN` the primary table becomes table_1 and there is no index uses so its doing a full scan. Why wouldn't it join the index for b.item_id?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN output when you rewrite the query as - `SELECT a.id,b.item_name FROM table_1 as a, table_2 as b where a.item_id = b.item_id` ?

Comment: Please always post full explain output. Its much more precise than attempting to describe it in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to do a full scan on at least one table, as you are requesting all records. It sounds like it picked table_1. The index should be used on table_2.

If you additionally add a where clause, you can avoid that table scan. But if you actually need all rows, then a scan is the quickest way to get them.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing a table scan because you ask for all rows that match. Add a `WHERE a.id = <any id>` and it should use the index.